# Why is the index method working but the show method isn't?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, routes

The following is my routes.rb file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  #Routes
  get 'users/s/:username', to: "users#search"
  resources :users, only: [:index, :show, :create, :update, :destroy]
  resources :forum_threads, only: [:index, :show, :create, :update, :destroy] do
    resources :comments, only: [:index, :show, :create, :update, :destroy]
  end
end
```

and this is the relevant part of my controller for the comments:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
    #GET /Comments [Get all comments for a specific thread]
    def index
        @Comments = Comment.where("ForumThread_id = ?", params[:forum_thread_id])
        render json: @Comments
    end

    #GET /Comments/:id [Get a specific comment by its ID]
    def show
        @Comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
        render json: @comment
    end
```

I tried sending requests through Postman. The index method seems to work for comments ([as seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dw7eW.png)), but the show method does not seem to work ([like here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMm8b.png)). Why is the show method not working?

Comment: Note on typo: in the method `show` variable `@Comment` and `@comment` is different

capital `C` in first

Comment: @DeepakMahakale Yep that seemed to be the problem, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're using nested routes

So in this case you should be looking for `comment_id` instead of `id`

```
def show
  @comment = Comment.find(params[:comment_id])
  render json: @comment
end
```

You can check for the params with

```
rails routes | grep comments
```

Also, It is a best practice to search for the comment in the parent's scope

In your case `forum_threads`

Ensure you add an extra condition to get the comment that belongs to `forum_thread` using `params[:id]`

Something like:

```rb
@comment = Comment.find_by(ForumThread_id: params[:id], id: params[:comment_id])
```

If you have proper association you can rewrite this as

```
@forum_thread = ForumThread.find(params[:id])
@comment = @forum_thread.comments.find(params[:comment_id])
```